# ContentDocumentLink fires trigger multiple times on list insertion

Tags: trigger, contentversion, contentdocument, after-trigger, contentdocumentlink

We have a trigger on Order attachment insertion, so that a field is populated with a link to the attached documents whenever a user uploads one or multiple files to an existing Order.

We created the trigger on ContentDocumentLink object, and we started having problems because of DML Exceptions for hitting governor limits `System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101`, but actually the 2 queries inside the trigger are run only once. We noticed, with test class, that bulk inserting a List of files, fires the trigger as many times as the list size, instead of a single one, that is why the Exception is thrown. How can this be possible?

The trigger

```java
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
       ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler.afterInsert(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
    }
}
```

Trigger handler

```java
public class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler {
    public static void afterInsert(Map<Id, ContentDocumentLink> oldMap, Map<Id, ContentDocumentLink> newMap){

        Set<Id> cvIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (ContentDocumentLink dLink : newMap.values()) {
            cvIds.add(dlink.contentDocumentId);
        }

        Map<Id, ContentVersion> docVersions = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>([SELECT contentDocumentId, firstPublishLocationId, Id
                                                      FROM ContentVersion
                                                      WHERE contentDocumentId IN : cvIds LIMIT 1]); 

        List<Id> idOrders = new List<Id>();
        List<Order> ordersToUpdate = new List<Order>();
        for(ContentVersion cv : docVersions.values()){
            idOrders.add(cv.firstPublishLocationId);
        }

        Map<Id,Order> updateOrder = new Map<Id,Order>([SELECT Id, customField FROM Order WHERE Id IN :idOrders ]);

        if(updateOrder.size() >0){
            for(Order o : updateOrder.values()){
                    o.customField = 'custom';
                    ordersToUpdate.add(o);
            }
        }
        update ordersToUpdate;
    }
}
```

The test class

```java
public class ContentDocumentTriggerTest {   
    @istest
    static void  testingDoc(){
      ...//order creation
      List<ContentVersion> contentList = new List<contentVersion> ();
      for(Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'Penguins',
            PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
            IsMajorVersion = true,
            firstPublishLocationId = o.Id 

          );
          contentList.add(contentVersion);
      }


      Test.startTest();
      insert contentList;  //This insert fires 10 times the trigger
      Test.stopTest();
 }
```

**EDIT**
Following the hint from @cropredy I've tried to write a test class with a mass insertion of multiple ContentDocumentLink but I'm not able to achieve it, as even with only 2 objects I get exception

`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Document with ID: 0690D000000iIIQ is already linked with the entity with ID: 8010D000000QMqJ: [LinkedEntityId]`

Code is as follow:

```
@istest
static void  DocumentAttach(){
 //...order creation  with a list of 2 orders for testing
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
insert orders;

String before = 'Testing base 64 encode';            
Blob beforeblob = Blob.valueOf(before);
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.title = 'test content trigger';      
cv.PathOnClient ='test';           
cv.VersionData =beforeblob;         
insert cv;  //this insertion fires trigger on content document link 3 times       

List<ContentDocumentLink> cvLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink> ();

Id cdID = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: cv.Id].ContentDocumentId;

for(Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
  cdl.ContentDocumentId = cdID ;
  cdl.LinkedEntityId = orders[i].Id;
  cdl.ShareType = 'V';
  cvlinks.add(cdl);
}

Test.startTest(); 
insert cvlinks; //this fires the trigger 3 times
Test.stopTest();
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: this is most likely related to using `ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId` that behind the scenes creates a `ContentDocumentLink` to the Order (x 10). That operation might not be bulkified. Have your testmethod build CDL explicitly rather than implicitly

Comment: mmm no i don't have one... i will try to find some time to write one and test again.

Comment: @cropredy i've tried to create a test class with the creation of multiple contentDocumentLink directly but i'm not able to achieve it. I always get the exception 
 `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Document with ID: 0690D000000iIIQ is already linked with the entity with ID: 8010D000000QMqJ: [LinkedEntityId] ` Please have a look at the added code.

Comment: Get rid of the CV.firstpublishLocationId assignment when you build the CV.

Comment: Thank you @cropredy i've modified the code as you suggested and now i made a test inserting 10 orders, 1 contentVersion and 10 contentDocumentLinks (1 for each order). Debugging it comes out that inserting 1 contentVersion, triggers 3 times the contentDocumentLink trigger and the CdLink list insertion fires the trigger 3 times again,as it was the contentVersion. I modified the last test class,if you can look at that.Still unclear  why.do you have any good reference to better understand this relations? thx

Comment: thank you @PranayJaiswal it seems similar situazion, but actually also following the link in the answer i do not understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider a simple ContentDocumentLink trigger and helper inspector class

```
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) {
    TriggerInspector.log(Trigger.new);
}


public with sharing class TriggerInspector {
  static Integer beforeInsertCount = 0;
  static Integer beforeUpdateCount = 0;
  static Integer afterInsertCount = 0;
  static Integer afterUpdateCount = 0;

  static Map<integer,ContentDocumentLink[]> cdlsByInvocation =
        new Map<Integer,ContentDocumentLink[]> ();

    public static void log(ContentDocumentLink[] cdls) {
        if (Trigger.isBefore) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {beforeInsertCount++;}
            else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {beforeUpdateCount++;}
        }
        else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                afterInsertCount++;
                cdlsByInvocation.put(afterInsertCount,cdls);
            }
            else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {afterUpdateCount++;}
        }
    }

    public static String inspect() {
        return 'beforeInsertCount:'+beforeInsertCount + '\n' +
                 'afterInsertCount:'+afterInsertCount + '\n' +
                 'beforeUpdateCount:'+beforeUpdateCount + '\n' +
                 'afterUpdateCount:'+afterUpdateCount + '\n' +
                'cdlsByInvocation:' + cdlsByInvocation;
    }
}
```

Now, with some anonymous Apex that inserts an `Opportunity`, creates two `ContentVersion` and then inserts `ContentDocumentLink` (2)

```
delete [select id from Opportunity where name = '00Oppo'];
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(CloseDate = Date.today(), Name = '00Oppo', StageName = 'Prospecting');
insert o;

ContentVersion[] cvs = new List<ContentVersion>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cvs.add(new ContentVersion (
            Title = 'cv'+i,
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('foo')
,           PathOnClient = 'foo.csv'
    ));
}
insert cvs;

ContentDocumentLink[] cdls = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
for (ContentVersion cv: [select ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN: cvs]) {
    cdls.add(new ContentDocumentLink (
        LinkedEntityId = o.Id,
        ShareType = 'V',    
        ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId)   
    );
}
insert cdls;
system.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,TriggerInspector.inspect());
```

**What do we get?**

> Surprisingly, as you observed, the ContentDocumentLink trigger is invoked three times despite only a single DML insert

```
beforeInsertCount:3 // !?!
afterInsertCount:3
beforeUpdateCount:0
afterUpdateCount:0
```

Invocation 1 shows that a ContentDocumentLink is autocreated with a LinkedEntityId of the running user (prefix `005`). This gets created for the first `ContentVersion` inserted. Notice the `ShareType = I` (inferred permission)

```
1=(ContentDocumentLink:{Id=06A63000000MHQqEAO, LinkedEntityId=00536000004Ui8MAAS, 
  ContentDocumentId=069630000007z3PAAQ, ShareType=I, Visibility=AllUsers})
```

Then, the second ContentDocumentLink is created in a separate trigger invocation, also inferred sharetype and associated to the running user

```
2=(ContentDocumentLink:{Id=06A63000000MHQrEAO, LinkedEntityId=00536000004Ui8MAAS, 
  ContentDocumentId=069630000007z3QAAQ, ShareType=I, Visibility=AllUsers})
```

Finally, in a bulkified Trigger, the two `ContentDocumentLink` are associated to the Opportunity (prefix `006`) using the Sharetype as specified in the DML's SObject (`V`)

```
3=(
ContentDocumentLink:{Id=06A63000000MHQsEAO, LinkedEntityId=00663000008vAJmAAM, 
ContentDocumentId=069630000007z3PAAQ, ShareType=V, Visibility=InternalUsers}, 

ContentDocumentLink:{Id=06A63000000MHQtEAO, LinkedEntityId=00663000008vAJmAAM, 
ContentDocumentId=069630000007z3QAAQ,  ShareType=V, Visibility=InternalUsers})}
```

> So what can we conclude?

- SFDC auto-constructs a `ContentDocumentLink` in a non-bulkified manner for every inserted `ContentVersion` linked to the running user. Hence, any `ContentDocumentLink` trigger is executed non-bulkified and should refrain from doing SOQL if the ShareType is `I`
- SFDC does bulkified trigger on any bulkified DML of `ContentDocumentLink`. Here, SOQL can be safely executed.

> Is the behavior any different if `ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId` is non null?

YES (sort of). Consider this code:

```
delete [select id from Opportunity where name = '00Oppo'];
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(CloseDate = Date.today(), Name = '00Oppo', StageName = 'Prospecting');
insert o;

ContentVersion[] cvs = new List<ContentVersion>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  cvs.add(new ContentVersion (
        Title = 'cv'+i,
        FirstPublishLocationId = o.Id,
        VersionData = Blob.valueOf('foo')
        ,           PathOnClient = 'foo.csv'
  ));
}
insert cvs;

system.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,TriggerInspector.inspect());
```

The ContentDocumentLink trigger is invoked **twice**, each with **two** records

First invocation:

- `Record[0] is a CDL linked to the runningUser , shareType = 'I' (for CV[0])`
- `Record[1] is a CDL linked to the Opportunity, shareType = 'V' (for CV[0])`

Second invocation:

- `Record[0] is a CDL linked to the runningUser , shareType = 'I' (for CV[1])`
- `Record[1] is a CDL linked to the Opportunity, shareType = 'V' (for CV[1])`

> This suggests, when coding `ContentDocumentLink` triggers **to not use** `FirstPublishLocationId` as it is impossible to do SOQL in a bulkified manner, even by excluding shareType `I` records.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! So if I understood well, there's no way to have a bulkified trigger when inserting multiple files to an object right?

Comment: if you use my first approach, and insert _n_ CV, the trigger is bulkified on the _n+1st_ iteration and you should have code to ignore the first _n_ non-bulkified iterations as they don't build the CDL to the Opportunity

Comment: ummm.I've tried moving the triggers on ContentVersion obj, but when uploading (manually, not with tests or code) multiple files, the triggers where not bulkified and fired 3 times on each doc (2 for shareType I, 1 for CDL). Sorry for bothering, but it's not clear what you mean. Thank you :)

Comment: @cropredy Is Salesforce aware of this issue? Because this non-bulkified behaviour is really annoying and there's nothing elegant we can do.

Comment: @WillemMulder - I do not know if SFDC is aware of this issue -- you could atMention CA Peterson on twitter - he can be responsive to stuff like this

Comment: @cropredy Thanks; will do! :-)

Comment: @WillemMulder did Chris Peterson ever get back to you on this one?  Did you manage to code around it?

Comment: I'm seeing slightly different behaviour again. Given 3 CDLs for insert, iteration one has item 1, iteration 2 has items 1 and 2, iteration 3 has all 3 items... So I end up with 5 actions being carried out in all.

Comment: @RobCowell I did not have contact with Chris about this as far as I remember, but also I'm currently not working with Salesforce anymore and have left my previous company, so he might have sent a late reply to an emailaddress that does not exist anymore... Hard to tell :-) Good luck with it; hopefully you get things sorted out!